# Only allow ssh/vpn on OpenWRT

Tags: ssh, networking, openwrt, vpn

If I don't want to use wireless encryption, but I still want security and I want to use sshuttle (on the clients, see: https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle/) for tunneling everything through an SSH tunnel then what could I do to prevent ANY traffic through the router? OpenWrt 10.04 Backfire.

So the wireless clients doesn't get ANY traffic until they OpenVPN'ed or SSH tunneled to the router.

So if someone sees the unencrypted wireless connection, and connects to it, then it couldn't surf the net, because it's blocked "somehow" (<- the question is this). And he can't even see the connected wireless clients, e.g.: with using (wifi-iface section):

```
option 'isolate' '1'
```

So it could only see that there is the router, e.g.: 192.168.1.1 and has only 1 open port sshd on e.g.: 55555.

In this way the "real" (valid) clients could be sure that they connect to the good router & and the traffic would be fully encrrypted?

Comment: Your questions would be clearer if you stopped using "e.g." for everything. It doesn't mean what you seem to think it does and doesn't add clarity to your posts. Please use simple full sentences instead.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for `iptables`. First allow whatever ports you use ssh and your vpn on, then block everything else. You will probably need to allow port 53 UDP for DNS as well unless you have some alternate setup for that.

Comment: don't you wanted to say only leave SSH+DHCP open? why is DNS needed when everything goes through the VPN? (even DNS)

Comment: If you are creating the VPN by IP then routing DNS over it, that's fine, but connecting to VPN's by host name would require that DNS worked on the network without being tunneled. And yes if you are using DHCP you'll want that open too.